# Transfer-encoding: Chunked in django

Tags: python, django

I am doing a django app which accepts Chunked request from iOS and Android client.
But the request takes very long to finish, even with a small image.
and it hangs here for a long time

```
stream = request.META['wsgi.input']
with open('a.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(stream.read()))
```

and the file is corrupted, file size doesn't match.
Please help

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't let your web server handle serving static files to the client? Django is never going to be good at streaming images in this way.

Comment: I am uploading an image using stream, not serving.